# How can I check if a specific URL reserve match will work?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a `{% url form_entry %}` tag in my template, while the `form_entry` value comes from a database.

If the url can't be resolved, I'm getting a `NoReverseMatch`.
How can I check if the tag will succeed before actually running it and getting an exception?

Something like:

```
{% if resolvable form_entry %}
    <a href="{% url form_entry %}">click here</a>
{% else %}
    Sorry, not found.
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `as` option of the [`url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#url) tag.

```
{% url form_entry as the_url %}
{% if the_url %}
<a href="{{ the_url }}">click here</a>
{% else %}
Sorry, not found.
{% endif %}
```